# Use spring's objectmapper with kotlin fuel

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-fuel

I'm using fuel for http integrations in my kotlin spring app, there's is a way to use Jackson for JSON serialization/deserialization.
But the mapper is a val in FuelJackson.kt.
Is there a way to override this with the Spring configured Jackson Objectmapper defined as a bean?

Answer (score 1):

Have a class accepting the spring initialised jackson objectmapper:

```
class FuelDeserializer(val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) {
inline fun <reified T : Any> deserialize() = object : ResponseDeserializable<T> 
{
        override fun deserialize(inputStream: InputStream): T? {
            return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream)
        }

        override fun deserialize(reader: Reader): T? {
            return objectMapper.readValue(reader)
        }

        override fun deserialize(bytes: ByteArray): T? {
            return objectMapper.readValue(bytes)
        }

        override fun deserialize(content: String): T? {
            return objectMapper.readValue(content)
        }
    }
}
```

This class can be added to you Configuration as a bean

```
@Configuration
class ObjectMapperConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(builder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder): ObjectMapper {
        val objectMapper = builder.build<ObjectMapper>()
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules()
        return objectMapper
    }

    @Bean
    fun fuelDeserializer(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): FuelDeserializer {
        return FuelDeserializer(objectMapper)
    }
}
```

Usage is then like this

```
@Controller
class PdfGeneratorApi( 
    val fuelDeserializer: FuelDeserializer
) {

    fun postSomething(): ResponseEntity<?> {
        "http://exampl.com"
            .httpPost()
            .body("Something to post")
            .responseObject<MyObject>(fuelDeserializer.deserialize()) {_, _, result -> 
            when (result) {
                is Result.Failure -> logger.warn(result.getException()) { "Failure while posting" }
                is Result.Success -> ResponseEntity.ok(result.get())
            }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The defaultMapper in FuelJackson.kt is a val, but that doesn't mean you can't register modules to it.

You can do something like this in a configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

  @Bean
  /**
   * Single place to get object mapper specific modules registered.
   *
   * @return ObjectMapper with necessary modules registered
   */
  public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.registerModule(new KotlinModule());
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    // it won't be the exact same object mapper used throughout 
    // your spring application, but you can make the fuel mapper 
    // match right here in the bean. 
    FuelJacksonKt.getDefaultMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    return mapper;
  }
}
```

I totally get that this doesn't give a person all the control they might want, but it does work, and it saves you from having to autowire a bean into every place you use fuel.

Comment: Good to know, but I wanted to reuse the already configured ObjectMapper from Spring. Registering modules for every ObjectMapper instance ins't very reusable.

Comment: @TomdeVroomen Actually that's what I mean. I have a jackson configuration class with an ObjectMapper bean. In that bean, I modify the global mapper used by fuel to match the bean. Here, I'll make an edit.

Comment: Ah, nice!  
The only issue I can foresee is when there are multiple ObjectMapper beans configured in the context, it probably is unclear which is Fuel's defaultMapper